# Download image from url on iOS React Native FS

Tags: ios, react-native

I use react-native-fs to download image from url in iOS. I check on simulator it's download success with path:

> /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/443C8F7F-AB92-4217-A999-A7BDBA52A6B6/data/Containers/Data/Application/99958A5C-E350-4855-B8CE-ED6FA999C619/Documents.

On real device, it's path (iPhone 8 Plus):

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63F84623-E684-456F-A55A-01E22708C012/Documents/pexels-photo-1109561.jpeg

I try set: `const destPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/images/' + name;`

because when i pick image from photo on real device this is path:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8DE01885-DEFE-4667-B6FF-CE693A0DADB3/Documents/images/1520FCA5-80AB-4300-A7F6-2D2C974D726A.jpg

but it't not work. I want to this image display on photo, this mean after download success i can see it on my photo immediately, how can do that and what about the others file like: mp3, mp4, text, after download, how to find it's and show for user when they want to read?

**This is my code:**

```
    downloadImage = () => {
   // download(this.props.image.url, '_Subiz/image_' + this.props.image.name);

   this.download(this.props.image.url, `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/react-native.png`)

  };


  download = async (target, destination) => {
    try{
      let options = {
        fromUrl: target,
        toFile: destination,
        begin: (res) => {
          console.log(res)
        },
        progress: (data) => {
          console.log(data)
        },
        background: true,
        progressDivider: 1
      };
      console.log(options);
      const request = await RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise
      console.log(request)
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob library. You can download simple way yor image. And also you can see it in Photo library

```
const { fs } = RNFetchBlob;
let Picture = fs.dirs.PictureDir;

 RNFetchBlob
          .config({
                appendExt : 'png',
                fileCache: true,
                path:  Picture+(new Date()).getTime()+'.png',
           })
          .fetch('GET', 'image_url')
          .then((resp) => {
            // the image path you can use it directly with Image component
            console.log(resp.path());
            return resp.readFile('base64'); // If you get base64 file
          })
          .then((base64Data) => { 
            console.log(base64Data);
          }).catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
            // error handling
            console.log('errorMessage2:'+errorMessage)
          });
```

Comment: I try and it's not work. I can't see image in library on my iPhone. This is path after download done: `=================================> ', '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9481E826-47FF-4BF0-B0E3-784161F01F00/Documents/RNFetchBlob_tmp/RNFetchBlobTmp_9mqxc3swc17k85gnnva53'`

Comment: check my updating answers

Comment: Thank for answer but Picture is `undefined` and it's not working

Comment: Are u sure define let Picture = fs.dirs.PictureDir;

Comment: can u log it console.log(fs.dirs.PictureDir); // what is the log?

Comment: this is log here: [Image log](https://filev4.subiz.com/fiqefsshoolonvwukqud-screen_shot_2018_11_15_at_3_56_50_pm.png)

Comment: can u know that chorme browser log? And also you can add some word before the log to see easly  console.log('PATH FILE: ', fs.dirs.PictureDir); if you can get the correct file path you can download image to galery

Comment: It's `undefined `. You can try by yourself.

Comment: I think that you dont install RNFetchBlob library in corectly

Comment: maybe u dont importt RNFetchBlod import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';